# Is retain cycle posible in computed properties?

Tags: ios, swift

I found a snipped of code there was a class, and that class had computed property of CustomViewController(inherits UIViewController) and in the getter of this property, they store self. The best way hot to describe this is via code

```
class SomeClass: {

    var alertViewController: UIViewController? {
        if self.wasRequested {
            return self.chatController
        } else {
            let vc = CutomVC(nibName: "SomeNibName", bundle: nil)
            vc.alert = self
            return vc
        }
    }
}
```

Now when you present that viewcontroller will this ever be de-inited? Is this retain cycle?

Thank you

Comment: does `self` store the result of that method at all? aka does it have a reference to that computed CustomVC, cause if it doesnt i dont think it would be a retain cycle. but probably wouldnt hurt to make `vc.alert` a weak reference if it isnt already

Comment: `vc.alert` should probably be left as a strong reference. If the result of this method was presented in another view controller `vc.alert` will be nil whenever `self` is not strongly retained elsewhere, which may be before `vc` is done using it. This whole thing seems like a strange design pattern.

Comment: Yes it is indeed strange :), but I was curious what will happen..thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to simplify things to other people interested in quick answer, NO this isn't a retail cycle, deinit is always called in this case.

Answer (score 1):

`Self` will be deallocated whenever the `vc` variable is deallocated, assuming it isn't strongly referenced elsewhere. This is not a retain cycle because `self` doesn't strongly reference `vc`.

However, if `self` added `vc` as a child view-controller (by presenting or otherwise) `self` **would** be holding a strong reference to `vc`. This is technically a retain cycle, but it's irrelevant because whenever `self` is removed from its parent view controller `self` removes all references to its own child view-controllers. This breaks the retain cycle between `self` and `vc`.

Comment: Imagine CollectionView controller, which displays for example books(title, author, image), collectionView data source would be an array of [Alerts] ant this class Alert would have that computed property alertViewController, which would be presented on didSelect. This is what is happening...that computed property then is in navigationStack, and then Im confused and curious.

Comment: This would be a retain cycle if the array of Alerts was retained by the same view controller that each alert is retaining. This will cause a retain cycle even if each view controller is removed from its super view controller because the array of Alerts will not be dereferenced

Comment: Yea, it's still a leak if each Book object is holding an Alert that is holding a reference to the object that owns the Books array.

Comment: I think this is little bit different, you have array of [BookClass] (CollectionViewController's data source), ClassBook has computed property (lets call it detailVC)  of type BDVC(BookDetailVC) and that BDVC has property (let's call it book) of type BookClass which is set in that getter. Whenever you access variable detailVC, it is computed property so new instance is created. I don't actually think that BookClass has strong reference to BDVC...when I test it, deinit of BDVC is always called

Comment: Yea, if dealloc is being called by all the objects and view controllers (when they are dismissed) then you're good.